# Trouble adding tensorflow dependency for scala 2.12.11

Tags: scala, tensorflow, intellij-idea

I am following a tutorial to perform object detection in scala. I am
having issues adding the tensorFlow dependency. I have followed the instructions on the official Tensorflow for Scala website http://platanios.org/tensorflow_scala/installation.html, but that doesn't seem to work. I also made sure to use the Java 11 JDK for the project. However, whenever I try to add the sbt dependency 
`libraryDependencies += "org.platanios" % "tensorflow" % "0.4.0" classifier "linux-cpu-x86_64"`, I get a "No dependencies found for given import" error in IntelliJ. Any idea on how to set this up properly ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace one `%` in your dependency line to twice `%%`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.platanios" %% "tensorflow" % "0.4.0" classifier "linux-cpu-x86_64"
```

Answer (score 2):

On top of what [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62483025/3314107) already suggested, I believe it's probably worth mentioning that (until 2.12) libraries in the 2.x are not binary-compatible across versions. The convention for Scala libraries is to append a `_2.x` to the published library JAR's artifact identifier. Since SBT was built around Scala (and it's its *de facto* standard build tool) it acknowledges this conventions and the `%%` operator will automatically append that extra "qualifier" based on the Scala version you are using.

Notice [here on mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.platanios/tensorflow_2.12/0.4.0) how the artifact identifier changes between the Maven and the SBT dependency declaration (in Maven, the artifact identifier is `tensorflow_2.12`, in SBT the `%%` allows you to not have to specify that).

The single `%` is generally used for Java dependencies (that are not affected by the aforementioned convention).

As an alternative (that I would suggest just to play around and see that there's no magic involved), you can also use `%` to specify a Scala dependency and explicitly mention the Scala version in the artifact identifier, as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.platanios" % "tensorflow_2.12" % "0.4.0" classifier "linux-cpu-x86_64"
```

The good news is that starting from Scala 2.13 this issue was tackled at the very root using an intermediate representation that was also introduced to make sure the interoperability between Scala 2.13 and Scala 3.x compiled code.

#### EDIT

What you have found was actually an issue in the documentation that was [already reported](https://github.com/eaplatanios/tensorflow_scala/issues/176), I opened [a PR](https://github.com/eaplatanios/tensorflow_scala/pull/183) to fix it.

Comment: Thanks stefano for the help !

Comment: So I found a work around, but adding the dependency in IntelliJ still doesn't work. Do I need to add a specific remote JAR repo ?

Comment: I thought you mentioned the other answer did the trick. If the problem is just IntelliJ, first try to build your project from the CLI. If it works and IntelliJ still doesn't work (after waiting for it to finish indexing), look for the command to clear the cache and restart, that sometimes helps.